# how to push folders from computer into sdcard using adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

If I have a folder structure in my computer such as A\B and the B subfolder contains 5 files, if I issue the command

```
adb push c:\programs\A\*.* /sdcard/fooBar
```

it copies all the 5 files inside the B subfolder into /sdcard/fooBar
How do I copy the entire subfolder B into the android device so that the fodler structure inside the device looks like `/sdcard/fooBar/B/5-files`?

Comment: download "cygwin" and use a real command interpreter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: Recursive copy with adb push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145872/android-recursive-copy-with-adb-push)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use `\*.*` may be ok

```
adb push c:\programs\A\ /sdcard/fooBar/
```

Comment: I want to do it without having to mkdir

Comment: you don't use \*.* may be ok
try `adb push c:\programs\A\ /sdcard/fooBar/ `

Comment: it doesn't copy the folder

Answer (score 10):

```
adb push c:\programs\A\B /sdcard/fooBar/B
```

Comment: This is a working, one-line, solution! No need to `mkdir`. Folder `B` will be created automatically.

Answer (score 6):

I've struggled with this question myself and it is clear that both answers do not actually answer the question.

To `adb push` to the SD Card, do *not* use `/sdcard`; that's your internal storage!

To push to your SD Card, first, you need to drop to `adb shell` in order to find it.

```
❯ adb shell
phoenix_sprout:/ $
```

Once in the shell, let's find it.

```
phoenix_sprout:/ $ cd storage
phoenix_sprout:/storage $ ls
C1ED-8A74  emulated  self
```

On that phone, the SD Card is at `/storage/C1ED-8A74`.

```
phoenix_sprout:/storage $ cd C1ED-8A74/                                                            
phoenix_sprout:/storage/C1ED-8A74 $ ls
Alarms   Audiobooks  Documents  Movies  Notifications  Podcasts   UI
Android  DCIM        Download   Music   Pictures       Ringtones
```

You can verify that this is the SD Card by checking the folder's content and matching it with what's on your phone's file manager.

Now you can exit from the `adb shell` and push stuff.

```
adb push A /storage/C1ED-8A74/
```

Congrats! You've now got `A` and its subfolders in your SD Card.