# Android emulator "adb push" not working (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I'd like to open local web pages on an android emulator, so I created an emulator API 14 (Android 4.0) and I launched it from the AVD manager.
Next step: move my files from pc to emulator and open it in a browser. That's the problem...

I'm trying the following commands:

```
adb push C:\My\local\directory sdcard
adb push C:\My\local\directory /sdcard
adb push C:\My\local\directory /mnt/sdcard
adb push C:\My\local\directory /storage/sdcard
```

The result is always the same:

```
push: C:\My\local\directory/subdirectory/file2.txt -> sdcard/subdirectory/file2.txt
failed to copy 'C:\My\local\directory/subdirectory/file2.txt' to 'sdcard/subdirectory/file2.txt': No such file or directory
```

If I run the shell I can see the sdcard folder:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\and-s-ws\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
# ls
ls
acct
cache
config
d
data
default.prop
dev
etc
init
init.goldfish.rc
init.rc
mnt
proc
root
sbin
sdcard
sys
system
ueventd.goldfish.rc
ueventd.rc
vendor

# cd sdcard
cd sdcard
# ls
ls
```

Any help?
Thanks
    #

Comment: run `adb -h` and search for `adb push` under the section "device commands" , is it exists ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: Recursive copy with adb push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145872/android-recursive-copy-with-adb-push)

Comment: @ben75 I understand you markdown but this is not an obvious duplicate, I couldn't find that question because title seems so different from my problem; they only have the same solutions, but not the same origin. So sorry for this downvote...

Comment: @ainos984 I didn't downvote :-)  just vote to close as duplicate (does it solve your problem ? )

Comment: @ben75 yes, it solved my problem (or better, I understood there isn't a straightforward solution for the error) but the questions are different so I don't think is a duplicate case. Don't you think too? However, doesn't matter. I understood my problem that's the point of all :-)

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70375963/10046475

Comment: adb push yourFile.xml \C:\Users\yourUN\.android\avd\Pixel_4_API_29.avd\mnt\sdcard

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I understood the problem was the sdcard permissions. I changed the read-write permissions following this steps in the adb shell:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19221592/2090803

After that, the `adb push` command worked fine:

```
adb push C:\My\local\directory /sdcard/myFolder
```

The adb automatically created the new folder `myFolder` and pushed correctly the directory and all the subdirectories and files.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is destination path. you should add `/` to beginning of your destination path. Try this:

```
adb push  C:\My\local\directory\file.txt '/sdcard/path'
```

Comment: as You can see in the question, even this test gives error. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the folder structure. The folders have to be there before you start to copy because adb can't create them.

Comment: No it wasn't. As you can see in my answer, the problem was the read-write permission on the sdcard folder. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me:

```
adb push "local path" sdcard/
```