# How to copy files to Android emulator instance

Tags: android, android-studio

How am I able to push .txt files to the emulator using Android Studio?

Comment: **Those coming from search**: You can simply drag and drop. Scroll past the accepted answer to upvote the author.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use the ADB via a terminal to pass the file From Desktop to Emulator.

```sh
adb push <file-source-local> <file-destination-remote>
```

You can also copy file from emulator to Desktop

```sh
adb pull <file-source-remote> <file-destination-local>
```

How ever you can also use the Android Device Monitor to access files. Click on the Android Icon which can be found in the toolbar itself. It'll take few seconds to load. Once it's loaded, you can see a tab named "File Explorer". Now you can pull/push files from there.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using Android studio like how we used to do in Eclipse.@shifar

Comment: there is no tab named File Explorer in Android Studio 1.2

Comment: Go it..ADM opens new window just like eclipse UI

Comment: yes, Android Device Monitor opens new window similar to the Eclipse DDMS

Comment: On Android Studio, when creating a new emulator, be sure to specify lie 1GB for external memory

Comment: This worked, but it certainly isn't the whole story when pulling a single file. When using `adb pull` the destination path has to be a relative path on Windows. Absolute paths don't seem to work.

Answer (score 298):

One easy way is to drag and drop.  It will copy files to /sdcard/Download.  You can copy whole folders or multiple files.  Make sure that "Enable Clipboard Sharing" is enabled. (under ...->Settings; see toggle in screenshot)

[image]

Comment: can't find - "Enable Clipboard Sharing". where is it on macbook?

Comment: The /sdcard/Download folder is still empty after file upload.

Comment: I found the folder I copied in Download of internal storage and not the sdcard.

Comment: Drag and Drop from Desktop to Emulator which is running the app.  Then go to device explorer to verify.

Comment: I had to run Android Emulator with --writable-system for this to work `emulator -avd <AVD_NAME> -writable-system`

Comment: If your file is on the Desktop in Ubuntu don't drag and drop directly from the Desktop but open ~/Desktop in the UI files window on Ubuntu and then drag and drop.

Comment: as simple as that

Comment: Please be more specific about where to find the clipboard sharing setting.

Comment: @ShirishHerwade @default123 You can find the `Enable clipboard sharing` settings in Android Studio's `settings > Tools > Emulator`. Sometimes when you first drag the file, it won't show the changes immediately. Sometimes you may require to refresh the screen to see the files.

Answer (score 160):

**Update (May 2020):**
Android studio have new tool called **Device File Explorer**. You can access it in two way:

1. By clicking on `Device File Explorer` icon in right bottom corner of android studio window.
2. If you could not find its icon, inside Android Studio press shift button twice. Quick search window will appear, then type `Device File` in it and **Device File Explorer** will appear in search result and you can click it.
   [image: open Device File Explorer]

Then you can navigate to folder which you want to push your file in it. Right click on that folder and select upload(or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>). Select file you want to upload and it will upload file to desired location.

[image]

**Push file using `adb.exe`:**

In Android 6.0+, you should use same process but your android application cannot access files which pushed inside SDCARD using DDMS File Explorer. It is the same if you try commands like this:

```
adb push myfile.txt /mnt/sdcard/myfile.txt
```

If you face `EACCES (Permission denied)` exception when you try to read file inside your application, it means you have no access to files inside external storage, since it requires a dangerous permission.

For this situation, you need to request granting access manually using new permission system in Android 6.0 and upper version. For details you can have a look in [android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292700/1080355).

**Solution for old android studio version:**

If you want to do it using graphical interface you can follow this inside android studio menus:

Tools --> Android --> Android Device Monitor

[image]

Afterward, Android Device Monitor(DDMS) window will open and you can upload files using File Explorer. You can select an address like `/mnt/sdcard` and then push your file into sdcard.
[image]

Comment: This worked for the copy logic.  However - using AS-ide 2.3 - in DDMS, the /mnt/sdcard will not appear as an expandable folder and appears as *empty* - even after restarting DDMS.  I verified the copy command worked when using `adb shell` to navigate to that folder. Thank you for  pointer to solution

Comment: Also you may select a folder, then right click and choose "Upload...", then select a path to a source folder or file.

Comment: got permission denied when pushing file to system, any idea?

Comment: old solution, thers no 'Android' tab under tools

Answer (score 66):

Android Device monitor is no longer available in android studio.

If you are using android studio 3.0 and above.

1. Go to "Device File Explorer" which is on the bottom right of android studio.
2. If you have more than one device connected, select the device you want from the drop-down list on top.
3. `mnt>sdcard` is the location for SD card on the emulator.
4. Right click on the folder and click Upload. See the image below.

Note: You can upload folder as well not just individual files.

[image: Device File Explorer]

Comment: This.  
I saved my file in the `sdcard/Download` folder,  then in the Emulator's file chooser application, use the Hamburger Menu and select the Downloads folder.

Comment: i put the files into sdcard/Download but emulators file picker shows nothing

Comment: It doesn't work. storage/emulated/ path is where we need to put our files but it says "Permission denied".

Answer (score 12):

I am using Android Studio 3.3.

Go to **View** **->** **Tools Window** **->** **Device File Explorer**.
Or you can find it on the Bottom Right corner of the Android Studio.

[image]

If the Emulator is running, the Device File Explorer will display the File structure on Emulator Storage.

[image]

Here you can right click on a Folder and select **"Upload"** to place the file

[image]

I usually use mnt - sdcard - download folder.
Thanks.

Comment: Each Android version has a different folder can you tell us about each version like 30, 29, 28, 27, 26... that will be useful information

Answer (score 10):

After you drag and drop your files from Desktop to Emulator like this answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44885506/3904109

Your location of files will be

Android 19, 21, 22  `/storage/sdcard/Download`

Android 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 `/storage/emulated/0/Download`

Answer (score 9):

Open command prompt and give the platform-tools path of the sdk.
Eg:- C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>
Then type 'adb push' command like below,

C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>[adb push C:\MyFiles\fileName.txt  /sdcard/fileName.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBFto.png)

This command push the file to the root folder of the emulator.

Answer (score 5):

refer `johnml1135` answer, but not fully work.

after self investigate, using [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator?utm_source=android-studio), it works now:

and use `Drag and Drop` **actually** worked, but use android self installed app `Download`, then you can **NOT** find the copied file, for not exist so called `/sdcard/Download` folder.

finally using other file manager app, like

**[ES File Explorer](http://shouji.360tpcdn.com/190524/efd2b85f04f57846c04baeafcd7a7e1f/com.estrongs.android.pop_10026.apk)**

[image]

then can see the really path is

`/storage/emulated/0/Download/`

which contains the copied files, like

`/storage/emulated/0/Download/chenhongyu_lixiangsanxun.mp3`

[image]

after drag and drop more mp3 files:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I used the filepath `/storage/emulated/0/Downloads` and it worked right away.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to drag and drop to the corresponding directory in the ADB

Answer (score 0):

adb push [file path on your computer] [file path on your mobile]

Answer (score 0):

on windows 10 , android studio emulator.
be on the directory yourFile.xml is.
on terminal, command:

```
 adb push yourFile.xml \C:\Users\yourUN\.android\avd\Pixel_4_API_29.avd\mnt\sdcard
```

Pixel_4_API_29 is the emulator name , choose the device you are using on emulator