# Push a bunch of files to Android Studio emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb, ddms

I want to put some files, as matter of fact, there are many (about 50 or 70), to       `sd card emulator` or wherever is possible.

I tried the topic below,
[How to Push Files to an Emulator Instance using android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434451/how-to-push-files-to-an-emulator-instance-using-android-studio)

and I even failed to push one file.

Following the topic:
In the `DDMS`,`Explorer` everything is disabled.
[DDMS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2NTJ.png)

Using ADB, I got the message below:

> `adb` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

... and I'm not quite sure how to use `adb`; What is the meaning of `<local>` or `<remote>`; how `adb` can understand where the file I want to send are?!
and is it possible to push a folder with more than one files included?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, try running the Emulator before you run the explorer, inversely try running the explorer then the Emulator.

Run AVD first, then once that is launched open the emulator you wish to access. The AVD should update and allows access to the files within the emulator. I had the same problem where I couldn't access the SD within AVD because the emulator was already running.

I noticed you are using Android Studio version 2.2, it may be worth trying to update to the latest version and if you are using any older version emulators, discard them and start fresh.

Comment: As you can see in the picture the `emulator` is running. 
I waited for some changes and nothing happened in the end.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version and unfortunately, no change!!
I really don't know what the problem with my system is !?
Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Wow!! finally, the problem solved. Thanks of both of you guys.
I upgraded to the latest version and I tried to run the Emulator and then AVD nothing happened; frustrating.
For once again I desperately tried what @Paul Jay said and this time, it worked.
Thankyou!