# Using file from internal memory on Android thing

Tags: android, android-things

I am newly working with Android (Android thing Pico i.MX7D I/O).

On my project, I'm parsing G code file line by line and giving corresponding outputs through GPIO pins.

Now, I am accessing the G code files from Raw folder from app.

I'd like to access the G code file from the internal memory root folder. Is it possible?

How can I use internal memory in Android? Also, how to paste the file in root folder as a user like we do on our android phone?

Comment: I think that you can do that 100% same way as in `android` (without `things`)

Comment: @VladMatvienko Can you explain the way !

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768191/how-do-i-read-the-file-content-from-the-internal-storage-android-app) and  [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37860254/6950238)

Comment: `android-things` is just a simplified `android` with some modules cut off (like GSM). But the file system modules are just fine. So use any Android code for reading file in `android-things`.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Ok, But how can i save files inside the internal memory without coding.

Comment: you can eject the microSD card from your Android things board, insert into card-reader, and write some files there.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thank you : )

Comment: Or use `adb push <file (with path) on your desctop> <file (with path) on your android things board>`

Comment: @VladMatvienko As your instruction , its fine now .Pico i.MX7D I/O is not support micro SD card, so I choose to use USB port for file transaction.Its Ok now . thank you