# How can I connect to SQFLite database from outside of emulator?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

As a newbie flutter developer, my code to create database is following

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

Future<Database> getDB() async {
  var dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();

  print("dbPath => $dbPath");
  final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
    // Set the path to the database. Note: Using the `join` function from the
    // `path` package is best practice to ensure the path is correctly
    // constructed for each platform.

    join(dbPath, 'doggie_database.db'),

    // When the database is first created, create a table to store dogs.
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      // Run the CREATE TABLE statement on the database.
      return db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE dogs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER)',
      );
    },
    // Set the version. This executes the onCreate function and provides a
    // path to perform database upgrades and downgrades.
    version: 1,
  );
  return database;
}
```

I am able to connect to this database and it seems the values insert as well. However, I would like to be able to connect to this database using tools such as DBeaver or DataGrip. Now, since this database is in the emulator storage, I am not able to connect any of these tools to browser data.

I have create the demo of how I figured all of this. You can watch it on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/_5VH-LctvEY)

My questions are

1. Can I connect database tools such as DBeaver or DataGrip with storage inside emulator?
2. Can I create database outside of emulator so that I can connect tools such as DBeaver or DataGrip and work with data easily?

Please let me know
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use FTP or Network sharing to use a remote database. But it is overkill for your case.

You could also sync the database file with your computer using this method [How to copy files to Android emulator instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434451/how-to-copy-files-to-android-emulator-instance)

Comment: But, this copies the file to emulator. Does it maintain a single copy and sync?

Comment: If you use the sync option yes.

Comment: Didn't work either. It was copying files :(